# how to avoid two columns contain 0 in linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

assume as  i have to shown the list of value in the screen

iam taking the list using linq

```
    Student     English      Hindi     Tamil      MArathi
    -------    ---------    -------   -------    ---------

    Deepan      56           65          34         45

    Mohan       45           34          0          23

    Murali      56           89          0          0
```

Assume that  i have these values in db.....

I dont want to show if (tamil and marathi ) is 0.....if both r contains 0 means ....
   i have to avoid that row while taking from database  using linq ...eg(murali)...but i dont want to avoid Mohan.....pls give me the linq query

Now i tried this

```
   var ulist = (from c in CustomerTransactions
              where c.TransTypeID==12
                         select new
                         {
                             Student=c.Student,

                             English=c.English,
                             Hindi=c.Hindi,
                             Tamil=c.Tamil,
                             Marathi=c.Marathi
                         }).ToList().OrderBy(b => b.Student).Where(x => x.Marathi!=0 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine several conditons in a single `where`-statement:

```
.Where(x => x.Marathi !=0 && x.Tamil != 0)
```

This will select only those entries where both conditions pass (meaning both `Marathi` and `Tamil` are not `0`).

Comment: i tried ur condition but i need to omit only Murali(if both contains Zero),According to ur Query it can omit Mohan also....Please give me the exact answer......i need to omit only murali(Both contain zero)......i dont want to omit if only one contains Zero

Comment: @DeepanRaj No, it won´t omit Mohan as Mohan has only one attribute set to zero. You probably are missing something.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can use if **Lambda** is fine for you. You can **combine all the 3 checks** in first **Where clause** itself, instead of specifying the conditions at 2 different places.

```
    CustomerTransactions.Where(c => c.TransTypeID==12 && !(c.Marathi == 0 && c.Tamil == 0))
                         .OrderBy(c => c.Student)
                         .Select(c => new {
                             Student=c.Student,
                             English=c.English,
                             Hindi=c.Hindi,
                             Tamil=c.Tamil,
                             Marathi=c.Marathi
                         }).ToList();
```

Comment: i tried ur condition but i need to omit only Murali(if both contains Zero),According to ur Query it can omit Mohan also

Comment: @Deepan Raj It was my mistake. The answer has been updated, Please try now.